# Is any countable subset of an uncountable set closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider uncountable nonempty $X\subset\mathbb{R}^k$. I wonder if I choose $E\subset X$ such that $E={p_1,p_2,...}$ countable and infinite, then $E$ must be closed in X.
Also, if I choose such set in spaces other than Euclidean space, can I say any countable subset of an uncountable set must be closed?

Comment: $\Bbb Q{{{}}}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in general, no. For example, consider

$$
\left\{\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

When you consider your favourite sequence $a_1,a_2,\cdots$, be it in $\Bbb R^k$ or in another topological space, you typically don't expect its limit (or any of its limit points) to be one of the $a_i$-s.